# which class is closer to an element A or B in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, class

```
<div class='red'>
  <span class='orange'>
    <div class='green'>
      <div class="yellow">
         <p>who is closer to me red or green??</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

above is my html, `i want to compare green or red which one is closer to <p>` in jquery??, i tried  with

```
  $(this).parents().hasClass("red");
```

but that will not work for me.. help me..

Comment: do you want to know only parent div class name or want to compare green or red for which one is closer?

Comment: want to compare green or red for which one is closer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`.parentsUntill()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/) at this context,

```
var xCollection1 = $('p').parentsUntil('.red');
var xCollection2 = $('p').parentsUntil('.green');

if (xCollection1.length < xCollection2.length) {
    alert('red is nearer');
} else {
    alert('green is nearer');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qbdd/4/)

Comment: @chriz yeah obviously.. :)

Comment: incase both red and green is not there ??

Comment: @chriz Then we have to check another one condition additionally, that `xCollection1.length == 0 && xCollection2.length == 0`

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/f8yra/)</kbd>

One Way :)

```
$('p').click(function () {
    var cls = $(this).parents('div').filter(function () { //filter all div parents
        return $(this).is('.green, .red'); //filter element who have class green or red
    }).attr('class'); //get the attr of the first matched element 
    alert(cls);
});
```

---

Get element check console log

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/f8yra/1)</kbd>

---

**Updated after Comments**

<kbd>[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/f8yra/4)</kbd>

```
$('p').click(function () {
    var cls = $(this).parents('div').filter(function () { //filter all div parents
        return $(this).is('.green, .red'); //filter element who have class green or red
    }).attr('class'); //get the attr of the first matched element 
    alert(cls.match(/(green|red)\s?/i)[0] + ' is closer.');
});
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it, this way is better.

Comment: What if the first element with green or red has other classes on it?

Comment: @jfriend00 he need the first matching element .

Comment: He asked which is closer red or green.  What if the closest element with one of those classes on it has many other classes.  Then your algorithm would have the entire class name with all the classes on it, not just `"red"` or `"green"`.  TH OP didn't ask for the element.  They asked which color was closer.  That's my point.  Your answer needs more code to examine the resulting class name to see which one it contains to know which one is closer.

Comment: Please read my entire comment.   Your code isn't done.  It does not answer the question the OP asked which is "which is closer red or green".  You just get an element.  You don't answer the actual question, particularly if there are other classes on that element.

Comment: sorry @TusharGupta, i just need which is closer red or green, no need of whole element!

Comment: @jfriend00 got it sir sorry :) Updated .]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a relatively simple solution:

```
var item = $(this).closest(".red, .green");
if (!item.length) {
    console.log("no red or green parents");
} else if (item.hasClass("red")) {
    console.log("red");
} else {
    console.log("green");
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Xcz98/

---

And, in case you're curious, here's a plain javascript method:

```
// pass starting node and space separated class list
// returns the class from the list it found first or "" if none were found
function findClosestParentClass(node, classes) {
    var regex = new RegExp(" " + classes.replace(" ", " | ") + " ");
    var cls, match;
    node = node.parentNode;
    do {
        cls = " " + node.className + " ";
        match = cls.match(regex);
        if (match) {
            return match[0].replace(/ /g, "");
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    } while (node && node !== document.documentElement);
    return "";
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/f3dHm/

Comment: @chriz - added handling for the case of no red or green parents

Comment: @chriz - simplified a bit further by using `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`.

Comment: @chriz - added a plain javascript way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
var parents = $(this).parents('div').map(function() {                
      return $(this).attr('class');
    }).get();    

if(parents.indexOf("red") < parents.indexOf("green")) {
     alert('red is closer to me');   
} 
else {
       alert('green is closer to me');   
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f8yra/2/)

Answer (score 1):

So, the greater the index in the `parents()` array, the farther it is in the DOM tree away from your `<p>` element. Now it is a matter of traversing through the array, and looking at each class name.

To see which is closer in the DOM, you need to compare the index of each element that you want to check for.

In this case, elements with class `.red` is at index 3, and elements with class `.green` are at index 1. This means that green is closer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var indexOfRed;
    var indexOfGreen;
    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).parents().each(function(index, el) {
            if ( $(el).hasClass('red') ) {
               indexOfRed = index;
            }
            if ( $(el).hasClass('green') ) {
              indexOfGreen = index;
            }
        });
        if(indexOfRed < indexOfGreen) {
             alert('red is closer to me');   
        } else {
             alert('green is closer to me');   
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JvNmT/

Comment: Sometimes it is more clear what is happening, when you do not use all of the abstractions jQuery provides.